# XForms: CSS for a label

Tags: css, orbeon, xforms

I need just one word in a label to be red. When I have a static text, everything works fine, as you can see here:

[image: Static label with word in red]

But I want to use in the label the value of another control. I am trying to do this with:

```
<xf:label value="concat('Is your name is ', xxf:bind('control-1-bind'), ' ?')"/>
```

But how can I make the imported value `(control-1)` red?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<xf:label mediatype="text/html">
    Is your name
    <xh:span class="labas"><xf:output value="xxf:bind('control-1-bind')"/></xh:span>?
</xf:label>
```